# React TypeScript - passing a callback function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-props

The following code would have worked happily in JavaScript. I am using React+TypeScript, hence this is a JSX file:

Calling component:

```
<FiltersPanel onFiltersChanged={() => { console.log('I was called') }} />
```

Inner Component:

```
const FiltersPanel = (onFiltersChanged) => {

    const handleFiltersChange = () => {
        onFiltersChanged(); /* I am getting `TypeError: onFiltersChanged is not a function` */
    };

    return (<div onClick={handleFiltersChange}/> );
};

export default FiltersPanel;
```

Why is TypeScript complaining that it cannot find the function, while the function is certainly passed as a prop.

Comment: Is onFiltersChanged null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed the function as a props so you should receive it to your component as a props like this

```
const FiltersPanel = (props) => {  }
```

then use it like this

```
props.onFiltersChanged()
```

OR you can use destructuring like this

```
const FiltersPanel = ({onFiltersChanged}) => { }
```

so you can use it without the props object like this

```
onFiltersChanged()
```